# Correct way to share logic between Domain Model and View Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I'm rendering a Create.cshtml which is supplied with a new ViewModel(). Before I submit the form, I want to use Ajax to calculate the price. My View Model doesn't know how to calculate nor do I want to duplicate the functionality. This behavior resides in the Domain Model on the grounds of encapsulation.

Using Ajax, I'd like to call a 'Calculate' Action Method on a controller which gives the user a total price, prior to completing the form itself (before the Domain Model has ever been created).

How can I achieve this functionality without breaking encapsulation?

Note: Later in the process, the DomainModel will be used to Calculate prior to basket/payment/processing.

```
public class DomainModel
{
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public int Quantity { get; set; }
 public decimal Price { get; set; }

 public decimal Calculate()
 {
  return Quantity*Price;
 }
}

public class ViewModel
{
  [Required]
  public int Id { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public int Quantity { get; set; }
  public decimal Price { get; set;
}
```

Comment: I discussed with a colleague about placing the Calculate() into a base class, with parameters rather than using the classes own properties. The base class can be inherited by both Domain and View models, but, this just feels wrong.

Comment: You could delegate the responsibility of doing these calculations out to a separate class (TotalCalculator), and then use an instance of that class within the DomainModel and the ViewModel to do the calculation. i.e. use composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: @AdaTheDev What would be the difference with your method, and a static calculator? What's the benefit to having an instance in this case?

Comment: Would it be more appropriate to create a base class, soley with a calculate() - then inherit in both instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could utilize interface extensions and then have each implement a particular interface. For example:

```
public interface MyAwesomeInterface
{
    int Quantity { get; }
    decimal Price { get; }
}
```

Then:

```
public class DomainModel : MyAwesomeInterface

public class ViewModel : MyAwesomeInterface
```

Finally:

```
public static class MyAwesomeInterfaceExtensions
{
    public static Calculate(this MyAwesomeInterface foo)
    {
        return foo.Quantity * foo.Price;
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't cross my mind, and it's much cleaner than the original base class approach. Thanks again.